# apacite: How can I use \bibitemsep with natbibapa option?

Tags: spacing, natbib, apa-style

I'm using the `apacite` package, trying to format my reference list so that it is single-spaced but with a blank line in between each entry. From the documentation for apacite, it seems that the way to do this is to insert the code:

```
\setlength\bibitemsep{2\baselineskip}
```

But when I have the `natbibapa` option turned on, it seems to over-ride this command. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{author99,
title = {A fine title},
year = {1899},
author = {An Author and Another Bauthor and Yeta Cauthor},
journal = {Madness}
}
@article{author05,
title = {The best title},
year = {1905},
author = {An Author and More Dauthors and Whois Thisauthor and Heis Thatauthor},
journal = {Insanity}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\citet{author99}. \citet{author05}. 

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
\bibliography{test} 

\end{document}
```

If I remove the `natbibapa` option (and change the `citet`s to plain `cite`s), then the `bibitemsep` command is respected. I'd much prefer to use the `natbibapa` option though. Any suggestions as to how to get the lineskip working with `natbibapa` would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The `natbibapa` option loads the `natbib` package, and this takes over the formatting of the bibliography. Therefore

```
...
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\setlength\bibsep{\baselineskip}
\bibliography{test} 
...
```

will do what you want, where `\bibsep` is the equivalent parameter from `natbib`.

Comment: Thanks. I always received "undefined control sequence" because I tried to change `\bibsep` before `apacite` was even loaded. Your example pointed that out.

Comment: Same answer applies if you want to change the indentation of the second line of a reference. Do not use `apacite`'s `bibindent` or `bibleftmargin`. Use instead `\setlength\bibhang{0.5cm}`.